# Why am I getting an undefined reference to another file, even though I define the command I am using?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, linker, header-files

I am working on a project in C, though I haven't coded in C in about a year, and I believe I am making just a simple mistake, but I am unsure of what I am even supposed to google to help me out, so I decided to come here. I have a simple file called driver.c that goes as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include "printHello.h"

#define MAXLINE 4096

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char bfr[MAXLINE];
    fputs("$ ", stderr);

    while (fgets(bfr, MAXLINE, stdin) != NULL)
    {
        bfr[strlen(bfr) - 1] = '\0'; //replaces newline with NULL term. char
        if (bfr[0] != '\0')
        {

            printHello();
            //parseCommand(bfr); - this will be used eventually but tested with printHello()
        }
        fputs("$ ", stderr);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

Now, when I go to compile using make, or just using gcc on the command line, I get the following error on my MacBook:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_printHello", referenced from:
      _main in driver-5776c5.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

And this error on a red hat linux machine:

```
driver.o: In function `main':
driver.c:(.text+0x3c): undefined reference to `printHello'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [driver] Error 1
```

Now, it looks like it is seeing that printHello doesn't exist, however it does exist in both

printHello.h:

```
void printHello();
```

and printHello.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printHello(){
    printf("hello");
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? I've got a lot to do on this project, all of which is fairly easy, however I can't get going until I can simply run my program.

NOTE: Whenever I compile using make, a file gets created called "-Wno-objc-signed-char-bool-implicit-int-conversion"

my make file goes as follows:

```
#Define the gcc options
CFLAGS = -Wall -std=c99

#Define the names of the object modules
OBJS = printHello.o driver.o

#Define a pattern for building an object file from a C file.  Note:  The
#variable $< expands to the name of the first prerequisite.
%.o : %.c
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

#Define the default rule
all: driver

#Define a rule for building the executable.  Note:  Unlike $?, the $^ variable
#expands to all the prerequisites required to build the target.
driver: driver.o
    gcc -o $@ $^

#Define a rule to clean-up the mess.  Note:  Projects don't agree on whether
#to delete the library.  The rule below deletes it.
clean:
    rm -f *.o *.a driver *~
```

Any help would be appreciated, and as usual, please let me know if you need anymore info!

Comment: `driver: $(OBJS)`?

Comment: Yes!! @AnttiHaapala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `driver: driver.o` by `driver: ${OBJS}` in your makefile
in order to make the executable depend on all the object files (.o)

For now the makefile tells that only `driver.o` is required
to build `driver`, thus some functions are missing at link.